# How to set the value attribute of file input in laravel 5

Tags: html, laravel-5

I have tried like below.

```
{!! Form::file('image',$value=$fileN) !!}
```

But display an error like below.

> ErrorException in FormBuilder.php line 228:
>   Illegal string offset 'name'

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can't set the value attribute of a file `input`, you can create the file input using something like this:

```
{!! Form::file('image'); !!}
```

This will create the input. The value will be set when the user will click the input and select a file to upload.

To set up the value of a file input dynamically is not allowed for security reasons and it's not because of `Laravel` but a general rule. Please [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html) to know more about this.